# No history of yesterday activity

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I answered a question yesterday and also posted a few comment, but now everything has gone, no history of it.
nothing shows in my profile. What Happened?

Comment: You should still see it in your inbox, since you got some comments and inbox items don't get deleted when their target is deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You answered a question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18442713/check-if-list-contains-items-from-checkedlistbox

that was deleted by its owner. I'm not sure of the reason why they deleted it.

Deleted answers and questions don't show in the activity list within your user profile.

Comment: So I think this is not a good behavior to delete all history of a deleted question.

Comment: I'm just curious how did you find that question?

Comment: @VahiD Mods have a 6th sense that allows them to see your past.

Comment: @Mysticial So that is not completely removed, you need some divine power to see them. anyway, thank you.

Comment: almost nothing is truly deleted here…

Comment: @VahiD moderators do see deleted answers and questions in user's profile page, that's just one of their "powers". :)